# Styling text on image

Tags: html, css

I have an image and text on it in two different divs with a background color,
text in one div is long and in the second div is short but the width of both divs are equal that is I don't want.
Here is my code:

```css
.banner{
  position: relative;
}
.banner img{
  width: 100%;
}
.image-text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 8%;
}
.image-text h2{
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
}
.upper-text{
  background: #2b96c3;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.lower-text{
  background: #0d729c;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="banner">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xTeFbiv.jpg">
    <div class="image-text">
      <div class="upper-text">
        <h2>Excellent Successfull</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="lower-text">
        <h2>Sustainable</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

All I need is like in the picture attached desired output:

[image: desired output].

I tried many tricks but not understand how to do this.

Comment: `.lower-text {display:inline-block;}`

Comment: oh man thanks buddy. it worked for me!

Comment: No problem - might as well close this question since it is doubtful that it will be helpfull for future users ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the display of the second div `inline-block` so it doesn't span 100% width.
Heres an example:

```css
.banner{
  position: relative;
}
.banner img{
  width: 100%;
}
.image-text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 8%;
}
.image-text h2{
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
}
.upper-text{
  background: #2b96c3;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.lower-text{
  background: #0d729c;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="banner">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xTeFbiv.jpg">
    <div class="image-text">
      <div class="upper-text">
        <h2>Excellent Successfull</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="lower-text">
        <h2>Sustainable</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```